# Animating to certain distance from div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a function in jquery.
If I click the button, it slide the page to special element

```
$('#tour_btn_1').click(function(){
    tourScrollTo('#tour_header_1');
});

function tourScrollTo(divData){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(divData).offset().top
    },500);
}
```

Althoug, if the width of the browser window ->(@media (max-width:1120px){}), is lesser then 1120px, i want it to slide slightly above the element
I want my code to be like this:

```
$('#tour_btn_1').click(function(){
    tourScrollTo('#tour_header_1',BODY_WIDTH);
});

function tourScrollTo(divData,BODY_WIDTH){
    $('html, body').animate({
        if(BODY_WIDTH>1120)scrollTop: $(divData).offset().top;
        else scrollTop: $(divData).offset().top+50PX ABOVE divData;
    },500);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add if check inside Object declaration better use conditional operator like below

```
function tourScrollTo(divData, BODY_WIDTH) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(divData).offset().top + (BODY_WIDTH > 1120 ? 0 : -50)
    }, 500);
}
```